# Set based updates in RavenDB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, curl, nosql, ravendb

I am working with RavenDB documents. I need to change a field in all the documents at once. I read there is something called set based updates in Raven DB documentation. I need a little help to put me in right direction here.

A patron Document looks something like this:

```
{
"Privilege": [
    {
        "Level": "Gold",
        "Code": "12312",
        "EndDate": "12/12/2012"
    }
],
"Phones": [
    {
        "Cell": "123123",
        "Home": "9783041284",
        "Office": "1234123412"
    }
]
{
```

In Patrons document collection, there is a Privilege.Level field in each doc. I need to write a query to update it to "Gold" for all documents in that Patrons collection. This is what I know so far. I need to create an Index (ChangePrivilegeIndex) first:

```
from Patrons in docs.patrons
select new {Patrons.Privilege.Level}
```

and then write a curl statement to patch documents all at once something like this:

```
PATCH http://localhost:8080/bulk_docs/ChangePrivilegeIndex

 [
  { "Type": "Set", "Name": "Privilege.Level", "Value": "Gold"}
 ]
```

I need help to get this to work .. thank you. I know there are lots of loose ends in the actual scripts.. that's why its not working. Can some one look at the scenario and the script above to put me in right direction.

Comment: Did you mean Privilege and Phones to be arrays in your example JSON? You access them as singletons in the query.

Comment: yes .. i know there is something wrong... I need to correct it.

Comment: Take a look at this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8263163/4500) my answer there should cover this scenario also.