# Errors updating Json with null array items

Tags: c#, json, patch, ravendb

I am modifying a Json document through code. The Json has array nested items. My code is failing because I believe its not able to handle Json documents where that particular array is empty. How can I check for null or empty arrays and make this code work for only arrays  that have data.

```
store.DatabaseCommands.UpdateByIndex("Raven/DocumentsByEntityName",
new IndexQuery { Query = "Tag:patrons" },
new[]
{
  new PatchRequest
      {
          Type = PatchCommandType.Modify,
          Name = "Privilege",
          Nested = new[]
           {
             new PatchRequest {Type = PatchCommandType.Set, Name="Level",  

             Value="Gold"}, 
           }
       }
}, allowStale: false);
```

Json document looks like:

```
    {
             "Privilege": [{
                           "Level": "Gold",
                           "Code": "12312",
                           "EndDate": "12/12/2012"
                          }],
             "Phones":    [{
                           "Cell": "123123",
                           "Home": "9783041284",
                           "Office": "1234123412"
                          }]
             "MiddleInitial":"F"

           }
```

Some Json docs can look like (notice Privilege is an empty array in this case)

```
 {
         "Privilege": [],
         "Phones":    [{
                       "Cell": "123123",
                       "Home": "9783041284",
                       "Office": "1234123412"
                      }]
         "MiddleInitial":"F"

       }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Patch through code - nested array items error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189208/patch-through-code-nested-array-items-error)

Comment: Thats deleted.. this is more to the point.

Comment: I don't really see what the `mvc` tag has anything to do with your question.

Comment: Which JSON implementation do you use?

Comment: I am using RavenDB documents... I am not sure what json implementation..

Comment: I would recommend to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249454/how-do-deserialize-this-json-into-an-object/8249611#8249611 . I could easily read your json strings and check for null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The patching command expects the data to be there, so you need to use an index to find the docs that don't have an empty `Privileges` list.

First you need an index like this:

```
public override IndexDefinition CreateIndexDefinition()
{
    return new IndexDefinitionBuilder<Patron>
    {
        Map = docs => from doc in docs
                      where doc.Privileges != null
                      select new { HasPrivileges = doc.Privileges.Count == 0 ? false : true }
    }.ToIndexDefinition(Conventions);
}
```

Then you only apply the patch to the docs where `HasPrivileges = true`, like so:

```
store.DatabaseCommands.UpdateByIndex("PatronByPrivilege",
              //Only apply the patch to Patrons that have a privilege
              new IndexQuery { Query = "HasPrivileges:true" },
                     new[]
                     {
                          new PatchRequest
                          {
                               .........
```

I've created a [full code sample](https://gist.github.com/1392443), any problems let me know.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you are trying to set a property on an array, but arrays don't *have* properties, they can only contain other objects.

Comment: So how can I do this in this case ? I want to change a value of "level" inside the "privilege" array ... Is there a different syntax ? Thanks for your help.